# AVCaptureDevice: Flash or torch?

Tags: iphone, avfoundation

Looking at [AVCaptureDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there are properties for both torch and flash settings. They both seem to have the same methods. I know that "torch" is the British pyromaniacs' word for flashlight, but do these really do the exact same thing with two different names?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The difference is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html). Basically, torch is used to continually illuminate video, whereas flash is used for image capture to brighten up the image. Hope that helps!

Comment: the provided link is out of date, Updated link to June '16: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html

Comment: Thanks! That will help a lot of people!